# SCCM client install failing, cannot get directory list

Tags: active-directory, sccm, windows-server-2019

I am trying to install the client on my test box, SCCM-Test-PC. The host server is SCCM3 and they are on a domain called ArchPixm.

When installing, I get the following errors:

```
GetDirectoryList failed with a non-recoverable failure, 0x80004005 ccmsetup 12/8/2020 11:17:20 AM 100 (0x0064)

Failed to get directory list from 'http://SCCM3.ArchPixm.local/CCM_Client'. Error 0x80004005 ccmsetup 12/8/2020 11:17:20 AM 100 (0x0064)

Failed to correctly receive a WEBDAV HTTP request.. (StatusCode at WinHttpQueryHeaders: 0) and StatusText: '' ccmsetup 12/8/2020 11:17:20 AM 100 (0x0064)

Failed to check url http://SCCM3.ArchPixm.local/CCM_Client/ccmsetup.cab. Error 0x80004005 ccmsetup 12/8/2020 11:17:20 AM 100 (0x0064)

Accessing the URL 'http://SCCM3.ArchPixm.local/CCM_Client/ccmsetup.cab' failed with 80004005 ccmsetup 12/8/2020 11:17:20 AM 100 (0x0064)
```

I went onto the test box and tried to access the site directly from IE with no luck (connection refused error).

I made sure that port 80 outbound and all WMI rules were applied on the client box, and the same inbound on the server.

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to bypass this by downloading the directory using WGET and running the installer manually. Obviously this is not a perfect fix to this problem and it wouldn't suffice outside of a very limited lab like I have, but it did fix the problem short-term.